# How Can i changed a fixed width of a div to a responsive expanding dive using a media query?

Tags: css, responsive-design, width, fluid-layout

Breakpoint 1:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:930px)
{
body{
    margin: 0,20%,20%,20%,20%;
}
    article {
    max-width: 50.125em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

i need to reverse the max-width i added in breakpoint point one so it goes back to a non-fixed width in breakpoint 2.

Comment: unrelated but your margin shouldn't have commas between the values

Answer (score -1):

If your `@media screen (min-width:..px)` for the second breakpoint is smaller than that of the break point one, go ahead and add the `@media query` after the first break point. But if the break point of the second is larger than the break point of the first, add the `@media query` of the second break point before the first break point.